# Introduction to a textbook on Minkowki spaces

Tags: geometry, reference-request, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to learn more about the metric spaces, specially the "Minkowski spaces" and "Zermelo navigation problem" on Minkowski spaces.

I have just studying the book " Riemann-Finsler Geometry" by Chern and Shen, which is interesting but non-rigorous in this setting.

Thank you for your help.